# Convert .TIFF to PDF in Angular

Tags: pdf, tiff

I need to do this convertion to use a preview component that use PDF

I try to use tiff2pdf but doesn’t have a documentation.

Also the visual studio code doesn’t recognize the import.

…………………..  ………..::..::::…
……………..////….